# Default HTML font size

Tags: html, css

I wonder what the default html font-size is and I can't find the answer.

What I mean is this :

What is the font size in pixels corresponding to this :

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

It could be useful to know this if you need to calculate rem font sizes.

Comment: I experimented a little bit and it seems to be 16px. Could anyone confirm?

Comment: IIRC, back in the day Netscape Communicator used 14px. But for a long time now, browsers have settled on 16px.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The default is 16px.

If you create an HTML file with any text in it, open it in Chrome, you can check the computed styles.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Completely forgot about the computed styles!

Comment: I was looking for the answer and I stumbled here, and this is the accepted answer, really?

Not only is 16px not a default, users are actually capable of changing 16px to anything and computed styles that you rely on won't save you...

Comment: What is 16px in pt?

Answer (score 23):

In the [W3 CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-size-prop), there is no definite default `font-size` other than the relative value `medium`.

That being said, a quick test with the developer versions of IE, Firefox, and Chrome all show that the de facto standard is 16px. I would be interested to see someone test this on mobile versions.

Edit: As of 2017-03-20, the stable versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE on the desktop as well as Chrome, Firefox, and Opera on mobile all default to the de facto standard of 16px for `font-size`.

Comment: +1 the only answer here that gave a nod to actually testing in different browsers.  Though now you need to add in mobile ;)

Comment: do you know the rationale behind the de facto standard? it would be awesome

Comment: @Webwoman I did some research and it sounds like the answer boils down to "because that's about how large traditional print media was when Microsoft was developing Internet Explorer". Here are my sources if you want to do more reading :)

https://blog.usejournal.com/your-body-text-is-too-small-5e02d36dc902
https://www.thomasphinney.com/2011/03/point-size/

Answer (score 7):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45AhK/1/)

Here's an easy way to check it:

HTML:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<span></span>
```

JQuery:

```
$('span').text("Font-size is: "+($('p').css('font-size')));
```

Output on Screen:

```
Hello world

Font-size is: 16px
```

Answer (score 5):

The default is browser-dependent. This is actually the very reason to using the `rem` unit. If we knew that the default is, for example, `16px`, there would be little point in using `rem`.

As other answers describe, the common *factory setting* default in browsers is `16px`. This can be changed by the user, in browser settings. In some browsers, you can set the size to any number in pixels, whereas some browsers have just a few alternatives, described verbally. In addition, the default font size can also be set in a user style sheet.